# Getting the last 2 directories of a file path

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipod-touch

I have a file path of, for example `/Users/Documents/New York/SoHo/abc.doc`. Now I need to just retrieve `/SoHo/abc.doc` from this path.

I have gone through the following:

- `stringByDeletingPathExtension` -> used to delete the extension from the path.
- `stringByDeletingLastPathComponent` -> to delete the last part in the part.

However I didn't find any method to delete the first part and keep the last two parts of a path.

Answer (score 11):

NSString has loads of path handling methods which it would be a shame not to use...

```
NSString* filePath = // something

NSArray* pathComponents = [filePath pathComponents];

if ([pathComponents count] > 2) {
   NSArray* lastTwoArray = [pathComponents subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange([pathComponents count]-2,2)];
   NSString* lastTwoPath = [NSString pathWithComponents:lastTwoArray];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've written function special for you:

```
- (NSString *)directoryAndFilePath:(NSString *)fullPath
{

    NSString *path = @"";
    NSLog(@"%@", fullPath);
    NSRange range = [fullPath rangeOfString:@"/" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    if (range.location == NSNotFound) return fullPath;
    range = NSMakeRange(0, range.location);
    NSRange secondRange = [fullPath rangeOfString:@"/" options:NSBackwardsSearch range:range];
    if (secondRange.location == NSNotFound) return fullPath;
    secondRange = NSMakeRange(secondRange.location, [fullPath length] - secondRange.location);
    path = [fullPath substringWithRange:secondRange];
    return path;
}
```

Just call:

```
[self directoryAndFilePath:@"/Users/Documents/New York/SoHo/abc.doc"];
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Divide the string into components by sending it a `pathComponents` message.
2. Remove all but the last two objects from the resulting array.
3. Join the two path components together into a single string with `+pathWithComponents:`

Answer (score 0):

Why not search for the '/' characters and determine the paths that way?

Answer (score 0):

NSString* theLastTwoComponentOfPath;
        NSString* filePath = //GET Path;

```
    NSArray* pathComponents = [filePath pathComponents];

    int last= [pathComponents count] -1;
    for(int i=0 ; i< [pathComponents count];i++){

        if(i == (last -1)){
             theLastTwoComponentOfPath = [pathComponents objectAtIndex:i];
        }
        if(i == last){
            theTemplateName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\%@\\%@", theLastTwoComponentOfPath,[pathComponents objectAtIndex:i] ];
        }
    }
```

NSlog (@"The last Two Components=%@", theLastTwoComponentOfPath);